# Loop and clear the basic function in R

Tags: r, loops

I've got this dataset

```
install.packages("combinat")
install.packages("quantmod")
library(quantmod)
library(combinat)
library(utils)
getSymbols("AAPL",from="2012-01-01")
data<-AAPL

p1<-4    
dO<-data[,1]
dC<-data[,4]
emaO<-EMA(dO,n=p1)
emaC<-EMA(dC,n=p1)
Pos_emaO_dO_UP<-emaO>dO
Pos_emaO_dO_D<-emaO<dO
Pos_emaC_dC_UP<-emaC>dC
Pos_emaC_dC_D<-emaC<dC
Pos_emaC_dO_D<-emaC<dO
Pos_emaC_dO_UP<-emaC>dO
Pos_emaO_dC_UP<-emaO>dC
Pos_emaO_dC_D<-emaO<dC
Profit_L_1<-((lag(dC,-1)-lag(dO,-1))/(lag(dO,-1)))*100
Profit_L_2<-(((lag(dC,-2)-lag(dO,-1))/(lag(dO,-1)))*100)/2
Profit_L_3<-(((lag(dC,-3)-lag(dO,-1))/(lag(dO,-1)))*100)/3
Profit_L_4<-(((lag(dC,-4)-lag(dO,-1))/(lag(dO,-1)))*100)/4
Profit_L_5<-(((lag(dC,-5)-lag(dO,-1))/(lag(dO,-1)))*100)/5
Profit_L_6<-(((lag(dC,-6)-lag(dO,-1))/(lag(dO,-1)))*100)/6
Profit_L_7<-(((lag(dC,-7)-lag(dO,-1))/(lag(dO,-1)))*100)/7
Profit_L_8<-(((lag(dC,-8)-lag(dO,-1))/(lag(dO,-1)))*100)/8
Profit_L_9<-(((lag(dC,-9)-lag(dO,-1))/(lag(dO,-1)))*100)/9
Profit_L_10<-(((lag(dC,-10)-lag(dO,-1))/(lag(dO,-1)))*100)/10
```

which are given to this frame

```
frame<-data.frame(Pos_emaO_dO_UP,Pos_emaO_dO_D,Pos_emaC_dC_UP,Pos_emaC_dC_D,Pos_emaC_dO_D,Pos_emaC_dO_UP,Pos_emaO_dC_UP,Pos_emaO_dC_D,Profit_L_1,Profit_L_2,Profit_L_3,Profit_L_4,Profit_L_5,Profit_L_6,Profit_L_7,Profit_L_8,Profit_L_9,Profit_L_10)
colnames(frame)<-c("Pos_emaO_dO_UP","Pos_emaO_dO_D","Pos_emaC_dC_UP","Pos_emaC_dC_D","Pos_emaC_dO_D","Pos_emaC_dO_UP","Pos_emaO_dC_UP","Pos_emaO_dC_D","Profit_L_1","Profit_L_2","Profit_L_3","Profit_L_4","Profit_L_5","Profit_L_6","Profit_L_7","Profit_L_8","Profit_L_9","Profit_L_10")
```

There is vector with variables for later usage

```
vector<-c("Pos_emaO_dO_UP","Pos_emaO_dO_D","Pos_emaC_dC_UP","Pos_emaC_dC_D","Pos_emaC_dO_D","Pos_emaC_dO_UP","Pos_emaO_dC_UP","Pos_emaO_dC_D")
```

I made all possible combination with 4 variables of the vector (there are no depended variables)

```
comb<-as.data.frame(combn(vector,4))
comb
```

and get out the ,,nonsense" combination (where are both possible values of variable)

```
rc<-comb[!sapply(comb, function(x) any(duplicated(sub('_D|_UP', '', x))))]
rc
```

Then I prepare the first combination to later subseting

```
var<-paste(rc[,1],collapse=" & ")
var
```

and subset the frame (with all DVs)

```
kr<-eval(parse(text=paste0('subset(frame,' , var,')' )))
kr
```

Now I have the subseted df by the first combination of 4 variables.
Then I used the evaluation function on it

```
evaluation<-function(x){
  s_1<-nrow(x[x$Profit_L_1>0,])/nrow(x)
  s_2<-nrow(x[x$Profit_L_2>0,])/nrow(x)
  s_3<-nrow(x[x$Profit_L_3>0,])/nrow(x)
  s_4<-nrow(x[x$Profit_L_4>0,])/nrow(x)
  s_5<-nrow(x[x$Profit_L_5>0,])/nrow(x)
  s_6<-nrow(x[x$Profit_L_6>0,])/nrow(x)
  s_7<-nrow(x[x$Profit_L_7>0,])/nrow(x)
  s_8<-nrow(x[x$Profit_L_8>0,])/nrow(x)
  s_9<-nrow(x[x$Profit_L_9>0,])/nrow(x)
  s_10<-nrow(x[x$Profit_L_10>0,])/nrow(x)
  n_1<-nrow(x[x$Profit_L_1>0,])/nrow(frame)
  n_2<-nrow(x[x$Profit_L_2>0,])/nrow(frame)
  n_3<-nrow(x[x$Profit_L_3>0,])/nrow(frame)
  n_4<-nrow(x[x$Profit_L_4>0,])/nrow(frame)
  n_5<-nrow(x[x$Profit_L_5>0,])/nrow(frame)
  n_6<-nrow(x[x$Profit_L_6>0,])/nrow(frame)
  n_7<-nrow(x[x$Profit_L_7>0,])/nrow(frame)
  n_8<-nrow(x[x$Profit_L_8>0,])/nrow(frame)
  n_9<-nrow(x[x$Profit_L_9>0,])/nrow(frame)
  n_10<-nrow(x[x$Profit_L_10>0,])/nrow(frame)
  pr_1<-sum(kr[,"Profit_L_1"])/nrow(kr[,kr=="Profit_L_1"])
  pr_2<-sum(kr[,"Profit_L_2"])/nrow(kr[,kr=="Profit_L_2"])
  pr_3<-sum(kr[,"Profit_L_3"])/nrow(kr[,kr=="Profit_L_3"])
  pr_4<-sum(kr[,"Profit_L_4"])/nrow(kr[,kr=="Profit_L_4"])
  pr_5<-sum(kr[,"Profit_L_5"])/nrow(kr[,kr=="Profit_L_5"])
  pr_6<-sum(kr[,"Profit_L_6"])/nrow(kr[,kr=="Profit_L_6"])
  pr_7<-sum(kr[,"Profit_L_7"])/nrow(kr[,kr=="Profit_L_7"])
  pr_8<-sum(kr[,"Profit_L_8"])/nrow(kr[,kr=="Profit_L_8"])
  pr_9<-sum(kr[,"Profit_L_9"])/nrow(kr[,kr=="Profit_L_9"])
  pr_10<-sum(kr[,"Profit_L_10"])/nrow(kr[,kr=="Profit_L_10"])
  mat<-matrix(c(s_1,n_1,pr_1,s_2,n_2,pr_2,s_3,n_3,pr_3,s_4,n_4,pr_4,s_5,n_5,pr_5,s_6,n_6,pr_6,s_7,n_7,pr_7,s_8,n_8,pr_8,s_9,n_9,pr_9,s_10,n_10,pr_10),ncol=3,nrow=10,dimnames=list(c(1:10),c("s","n","pr")))
  df<-as.data.frame(mat)
  return(df)
}
result<-evaluation(kr)
result
```

And I need to help in several cases.

1, in evaluation function the way the matrix is made is wrong (s_1,n_1,pr_1 are starting in first column but I need to start the order by rows)

2, I need to use some loop/lapply function to go trough all possible combinations (not only the first one like in this case `(var<-paste(rc[,1],collapse=" & ")`) and have the understandable output where is evaluation function used on every combination and I will be able to see for which combination of variables is the evaluation done (understand I need to recognize for what is this evaluation made) and compare evaluation results for each combination.

3, This is not main point, BUT I generally want to evaluate all possible combinations (it means for 2:n number of variables and also all combinations in each of them) and then get the best possible combination according to specific DV (Profit_L_1 or Profit_L_2 and so on). And I am so weak in looping now, so, if it this possible, keep in mind what am I going to do with it later.

Thanks, feel free to update, repair or improve the question (if there is something which could be done way more easily, effectively - do it - I am open for every senseful advice.

Comment: The code does not look like a minimal example. This is not a "debug my project for me site". Put some effort into making a minimal example and them say what you want the answer to be.

Comment: What @BondedDust said.  Half of the time, putting the example together leads you to your own solution.